# How to highlight mouse pointer area in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry, shader, mouse-position

I have a .fbx model rendered using ThreeJS.
I would like to display a circle on top of the model according to the mouse-pointer's position.
I am having a hard time finding an exmaple.
Is this done with shaders?
How?

Comment: Use `THREE.Raycaster()` for finding the point of intersection and then copy this point to the position of a marker (for example, a sphere).

Comment: I don't want a 2d marker, but kind of a lighting effect on that area.

Comment: Is there any chance to provide the code you tried to achieve the desired result? And would be cool to provide an explanatory picture with the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, to get real 3D point (in model space) from 2D (projected) screen point you need to use raycasting. Official examples are the best, I think.

[webgl interactive points](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=poin#webgl_interactive_points)

[interactive raycasting points](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_raycasting_points.html).

But I recommend to use GPU-powered raycasting - it is much faster, you will have much better FPS while mouse moving (it has some little bugs, though):
[GPUPicker](http://brianxu.github.io/GPUPicker/).

To draw lighting effect you need shader (and shader material for you object, placed to pointer-driven location).
See example [here](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=pick#webgl_fire).